# Reprojecting OSM vector Data in UTM32N EPSG:32632

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap, utm, cartesian

Unfortunately my QGIS doesn't really want me to change the Projection of the OSM Vector data. I downloaded processed Vector OSM Data which was in the (normal) Mercator Projection. I put the layers in QGIS and reprojected everyone of them separately in the same cartesian system (EPSG: 32632) and set the Project EPSG 32632. Then I saved the files to be sure everything is in the new projection. When I open the files however everything looks fine until I try to put a buffer around a POI or something else. It looks like the extension of my layers is like 50 centimetres now which cant be because the area I am working with is around 300km extended (minimum). When I use the original
(unreprojected files) everything is in perfect order, but I want to use it in UTM since I want to work with exact distances and metres/kilometres. Is it the files or did i reproject wrong (which I doubt since ive done it quite a few times and this never happened). I already tried reopening QGIS or reprojecting it again and I had the same issue.
[image]

Comment: We definitely need more details on this. How did you reproject? What distance did you buffer your reprojected data with? Can you provide a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: how did you reproject the data?

Comment: i have multiple layers e.g. osm_places, osm_pois etc. I opened them in QGIS. switched the EPSg in the bottom right corner to 32632, right clicked on the layer i wanted to reproject --> then on set crs --> set layer crs --> EPSG 32632. After this i went on export --> save feature as --> saved it as a shapefile in destined folder and reopened it.

Comment: Setting the CRS is not reprojecting. Hence your whole workflow is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

*Right click on layer to be reprojected -> Export -> Save Feature As... -> Change CRS to whatever you need (see screenshot below)*

This should actually reproject your files - just setting it will not reproject, it will assume your file is in this CRS already and just interpret it using the new CRS.

[image: screenshot export in new CRS]

Comment: Thank you very much i made it now! :)